# getting a specific row over a partitioned sql query

Tags: sql, partition

I know i can get first_value() and last_value() over partitioned sql query which is ordered by a column I know, but let's say I want the second value, or the third... Is there a function to do so? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no specific function for that. However you can select the second row like this:

```
with row_numbers AS(select row_number() over(order by yourColumn) as 'row', * 
                from table)
select * from row_numbers
where row=2
```

Comment: thank you, I thought there is a better way to do so.